# Defining new brackets

Tags: custom-notation

I would like to wrap double-struck brackets around variables for notation purposes only. For instance `[[X]]` should display as the first image below. However, these brackets are reserved for the built-in function `Part`.

At the moment, I use angle brackets and then replace these with the new ones via [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)). I apply this to lists of expressions involving elements as ⟨XY⟩ -> ⟨X⟩ ⟨Y⟩, where XY, X and Y are graphs:

```
(⟨XY⟩ -> ⟨X⟩ ⟨Y⟩) /. ⟨x_⟩ :> 
  GraphicsRow[{MaTeX["\\llbracket"], x, MaTeX["\\rrbracket"]}, 
   Scaled[.01], Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 40]
```

However, as shown in the second image, there are alignment and scaling issues. If the double-struck brackets are defined as a new notation, I could use instead

```
(⟨XY⟩ -> ⟨X⟩ ⟨Y⟩) /. ⟨x_⟩ :> [[x]]
```

which would keep XY, X and Y consistent with their original alignment and scaling.

[image: double-struck brackets 1]

[image: double-struck brackets 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `$Preprint`:

First define the variables you want to print with double brackets. Then define a `$PrePrint` function:

```
vars = {a, b, c};

$PrePrint = 
  With[{v = 
     Thread[vars -> ("\[LeftDoubleBracket]" <> ToString[#] <> 
           "\[RightDoubleBracket]" &) /@ vars]}, # /. v &];
```

Here is an example:

```
Sqrt[a] + b^3 - Sin[c]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Via the `Notation` package, one can define a new command:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[{"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", "x_", 
     "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]]\[DoubleLongLeftArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[{"ll[", "x_", "rr]"}]]]
```

which is displayed with the notation palette as

[image: palette2]

and which gives the result

[image: result2]